# How to operate a Kubernetes cluster on Digitalocean from Python?

Tags: python, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubeconfig

### the question

I am running a Kubernetes cluster in Digitalocean and I want to connect to it from certain Python app, in order to retrieve information about running services. I am able to setup the connection from my local (where `kubeconfig` created using `doctl` is present), however how to create a `kubeconfig` when the app is deployed (using `Docker`)?

### current state

So far the connection I use looks like this, the issue is with `load_kube_config`, because in my container there is not `kubeconfig`.

```py
import kubernetes as k8s
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException


def init_k8s():
    """
    Init connection to k8s cluster
    :return:
    """
    # Load the Kubernetes configuration
    k8s.config.load_kube_config()

    # Configure the Digital Ocean API access token
    configuration = k8s.client.Configuration()
    configuration.host = 'https://api.digitalocean.com'
    # configuration.verify_ssl = True
    # configuration.debug = False
    configuration.api_key = {'access-token': DO_API_SECRET}
```

### possible options

Please note, I am using Digitalocean Applications for build and run. This limits some options, as seen below.

#### create kubeconfig during `docker build`

One idea, is to create `kubeconfig` during build of the container, running

```
doctl auth init -t the-secret-token
doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save 1c08efb9-xxx-yyy
```

The only issue might with exposing certain variable during build.

#### ❌ map existing kubeconfig to the container

One possible option will be to somehow map the existing `kubeconfig` into the container during runtime. Unfortunately I have no option to do this *(it's deployed over Digitalocean Apps, not Kubernetes or so)*

#### ❌ copy existing kubeconfig during build

Also not possible due to point above - I am building the app in DO Apps and there is no option to copy the `kubeconfig`.

#### ❌ create base docker image

Create a new docker image containing the `kubeconfig` and use it as base image during the app build is one possible approach. However merging my secrets (`kubeconfig`) into an image which needs to be in public Docker registry is not possible

#### ✅ create kubeconfig during app runtime - THIS WORKS

The most optimal approach, so far, is to create a `kubeconfig` file during app runtime using `doctl` API (or lib like this). I am currently trying to figure out this way.

I am gonna dig and try more and more options. I will be glad for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out a way, how to do it using Digitalocean API.
Note that

- `DO_API_SECRET` is API key generated on digital ocean
- `DO_API_URL` is digitalocean base api URL, right now it's `https://api.digitalocean.com/v2`
- K8S_CLUSTER_ID - is the internal cluster id, I have copied mine from the browser URL and looks like `1c08ef14-zzzz-xxxx-aaa-qqqq`
- It is a good idea to remove the tempfile after it's loaded

```py
def get_kubeconfig():
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {DO_API_SECRET}",
    }

    response = requests.get(
        f"{DO_API_URL}/kubernetes/clusters/{K8S_CLUSTER_ID}/kubeconfig",
        headers=headers,
    )

    kubeconfig_content = response.text

    # Generate a temporary kubeconfig file
    kubeconfig_path = tempfile.mkstemp()[1]
    with open(kubeconfig_path, "w") as kubeconfig_file:
        kubeconfig_file.write(kubeconfig_content)

    return kubeconfig_path

path = get_kubeconfig()
k8s.config.load_kube_config(path)
```